# Populate ListView with ArrayAdapter and navigate

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

For example if I have a class:

```
class Folder {
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Folder> subFolders;
    public ArrayList<Folder> subFolders;
}
```

And I am trying to fill `ListView` with custom `ArrayAdapter` and then navigate through this `ArrayList` "Folders" which is filled with data. I try something like this to show `subFolders`:

```
private OnItemClickListener listlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, long arg3) {
        currentFolder = (Category) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        folders = currentFolder.subFolders;
        folderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

But it does not work. Is there any suggestions to help solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom ArrayAdapter create a Public method

```
public void setList(List<Item> items){
   this.items = items;
}
```

and now

```
private OnItemClickListener listlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, long arg3) {

        currentFolder = (Category) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        folders = currentFolder.subFolders;
        folderAdapter.setList(folders);
        folderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
```

Comment: when i do this way old object stay in the `listView`

Comment: how to handle with `getView()` method to display new data?